# Using docker GELF driver env/labels in logstash

Tags: docker, logstash

Docker GELF log driver allows `env` and `labels` log-opts:

> The labels and env options are supported by the gelf logging driver. It adds additional key on the **extra** fields, prefixed by an underscore (_) ([ref](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#/gelf-options))

I want to use this in my index name for elasticsearch output but I couldn't figure out how I can access these value or said `extra` fields.

Assuming that I have these options running a container,

```
docker run -it \
  --log-driver gelf \
  --log-opt gelf-address=udp://127.0.0.1:12201 \
  --log-opt tag=some-app \
  --log-opt env=staging \
  --log-opt labels=staging \
  ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash -c 'echo Hello World'
```

I'd like to use the `env` value that I passed in my logstash config as such:

```
input {
  gelf { }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "logstash-%{env-value-here}-%{tag}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

There seems to be another question about env/labels with Graylog: [Docker GELF driver env option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030555/docker-gelf-driver-env-option)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading the PR that added this option, I realised that I misunderstood how it was supposed to work.

`--log-opt labels=a,b,c` (same with env) define keys to include in the GELF event. The values are actually retrieved from docker labels and environment variables respectively.

`--log-opt labels=foo --label foo=bar` will include `foo: bar` in the event.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly and is much nicer than cramming multiple things into the tag. The docker documentation is really not clear here

Comment: Thanks for the enlightment! The Docker configuration is pretty much misleading here!